# How plot legend in ggplot graph with several variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code

```
ggplot(df.np.prod.cons.daily[df.np.prod.cons.daily$Region=="EE", ]) + 
      geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Production),  color="red", size=1) + 
      geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Consumption), color="blue", size=1)+
      geom_bar(aes(x = Date, y = prodVScons), stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', color="gray")+
      theme_economist()+
      guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))
```

My graph is looking:
[image]

How can I add the legend, which tells which color corresponds to which variable? (It will be also great if you help me to depict barplot as in one colour went the values are positive and different colour when it is positive- and then in the legend tell that variable prodVScons is with 2 colours)

Comment: Move `color` inside `aes`

Comment: ... and make use of `scale_color_manual(values = c(red = "red", blue = "blue", gray = "gray"))` to get the right colors.

Comment: I tried to change code in the same ways however, the legend did not appear on the plot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what your are looking for.

1. Following the comments by @AllanCameron and myself moving `color` inside `aes` and adding `scale_color_manual` will add a legend.
2. To get different colors for negative and positive bars make the color conditional on the value.
3. To get filled bars I also make use of the `fill` aes and `scale_fill_manual`
4. Finally, I decided for a line as legend key symbol and set the `key_glyph` to "`path"` for all three geoms

Using some random example data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

df.np.prod.cons.daily <- data.frame(
  Region = "EE",
  Date = 1:100,
  Production = runif(100, 20000, 30000),
  Consumption = runif(100, 10000, 20000),
  prodVScons = runif(100, -10000, 10000)
)

ggplot(df.np.prod.cons.daily[df.np.prod.cons.daily$Region=="EE", ]) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Production,  color="red"), size=1, key_glyph = "path") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Consumption, color="blue"), size=1, key_glyph = "path")+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Date, y = prodVScons, 
               color = ifelse(prodVScons < 0, "grey40", "grey80"),
               fill = ifelse(prodVScons < 0, "grey40", "grey80")), 
           stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', key_glyph = "path")+
  theme_economist()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c(red = "red", blue = "blue", grey40 = "grey40", grey80 = "grey80"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(red = "red", blue = "blue", grey40 = "grey40", grey80 = "grey80")) +
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image]